# Pattern for retrieving batches of Objects?

Tags: java, tdd, dao

This seems to be a recurring requirement for me, so I'd like to get some feedback on how to implement it and what sort of test code makes sense. I need to retrieve batches of data and stitch it together for further business use. I need to select all the As from 1 datasource and match them with any Bs from a second datasource. A has an id field, and B has an aId field which may match some ids. I need to return all A's with their matching Bs, if any matches exist.

Wanting to follow some good practices, I use DAOs, and Object models. This results in something like the below. Pretty simple, any feedback on this? Recommendations for test code -- I would write integration tests against the dao interfaces, but probably nothing else? What package name do people use for models -- is com.me.model reasonable?

```
    package com.me.dao;

    class ADao {
      public List<A> getAllAs() {
       return //Select aId, avalue1, value2;
      }
    }

    class BDao {
      public List<B> getAllBs() {
       return //Select bId, bvalue1, bvalue2;
      }
    }

   package com.me.model;

    class A {
      long Id
      avalue1;
      avalue2;
    } 

    class B {
      long aId
      bvalue1;
      bvalue2;
    } 

    class AWithB {
      A a;
      List<B> b;
    }
```

Also, where should the following code belong. This seems like it would be a misuse of a factory pattern, suggestions on what is appropriate here? Recommendations for unit testing this code?

```
List<AWithB> getAllAsWithBs {
  List<A> as = aDao.getAllAs();
  List<B> bs = bDAo.getAllBs();

  return combineAsAndBs(as, bs);
}

List<AWithB> combineAsAndBs(List<A> as, List<B> bs) {
  List<AWithB> aWithBs =new List<>;

  foreach (A a : as) {
    aWithBs.add(createAWithBs(List<B> bs));
  }

  return aWithBs;
}

List<B> createAWithB(A a, List<B> bs) {
  AWithB aWithB = new AWithB;

  aWithB.a = a;
  for (B b : bs) {
    if (a.id == b.aId) {
      aWithB.bs.add(b);
    }
  } 

 return aWithB;
}
```

Comment: Why not give `A` a list of `B`'s?